# Liferay 6.1.2 CE GA3 - Kaleo Web

Tags: liferay

I'm upgrading from 6.1 GA1 to 6.1 GA3, but have problems with Kaleo-Web 6.1 GA1. Could it be that it's not compatible with 6.1 GA3?

Comment: I've taken the freedom to reorder/rephrase your question - especially the version numbers. Please make sure I understood you correctly or edit again

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to marketplace and download the latest kaleo-web version. Most likely the GA1 version of the plugin is not compatible with Liferay GA3 - at least it has naturally not been tested. But plugins are typically released together (or shortly after) a new portal GA has been released.

Please download the latest version from the Marketplace and check its compatibility. By the way, this applies to all plugins that you have deployed, not just kaleo-web

Comment: I've taken the freedom to reorder/rephrase your question - especially the version numbers. Please make sure I understood you correctly or edit again